# Unity 5 UI - assigning Dropdown.value causes crash

Tags: c#, crash, unity-game-engine

Sooo, I have weird problem. Whenever I try to assign value to Dropdown.value everything is ok until this part gets executed during playtest. I mean, there is no error message, nothing, whole unity editor just crashes.

There is also no other possible error, I commented out whole script leaving only this and it crashed. Removing the line works but I need it to set default value to the dropdown when instantiating the object. I also try to assign numbers in range (13 elements, assigning 5 doesn't work either). It looks smth like this, really nothing complicated:

```
GameObject tempObj = Instantiate(PanelToInstantiate, this.transform);
Dropdown tempDrop = tempObj.transform.FindChild("Dropdown").GetComponent<Dropdown>();
tempDrop.AddOptions(GlobalData.ListOfStrings);
tempDrop.value = 5; //Normally some other variable, but I testes with straight number too
```

Full scripts on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UgWxhuXF

Options are added properly and are visible in inspector during playtest. Any change to dropdown.value through code ends in editor crash without any error messages. Could anyone suggest any fix? I tried to even remake whole instantiated prefab from scratch in case it got corrupted. I also checked the project on another machine and the crash still happens.

Unity version: 5.5.1f1

Languague: C# (Visual Studio Community with Unity addon)

Comment: wrap your code in a `try catch` and see what the exception is

Comment: Already tried it. Unless there is some special way to do so with VisualStudio Community in conjunction with Unity. Even with try...catch unity still crashes and I have no info. I'll look into debugging unity this way though, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I tried using try catch some more, with catching different exceptions (System.Exception and UnityException included), hooking VS differently to unity. Nothing gives any information about the cause of crash. 
Also I edited main post adding pastebin link with full scripts but dunno if that will help. My only idea now is to rebuild the project itself from scratch :/

Comment: Did you try:  ` void Start () { try {
       DataSource = GameObject.Find("GlobalController").GetComponent<PlayerData>();
       UpdateOfficersList();} catch(Exception ex) {} 
   } `

Comment: Yup. At this point i used try...catch in every place, still nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after 3 days, yay :D

So, the problem is, onValueChange gets called EVERY TIME value is changed. Even if it is through script. And here I added listeners in Awake, so they were added to dropdown right after instantiating... and then I changed value, which called those functions, which caused creating new dropdowns with the same effect,s, ergo infinite loop.

So the fix was to add listeners after changing initial value.

Thanks CodingYoshi for the help though :D

Comment: Thanks - I was stuck on this for an hour or two and while I solved it differently, pointing out that the listener being activated was key to what was going on. The debugger made it look like may exception was coming from me populating the dropdown, whereby it was actually coming from my listener which was being unknowingly activated by changing the value. I just guard the code in the listener better, I hadn't gotten around to that and was stuck on initialization.